# How to flip canvas using CamanJS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, camanjs

So i want to create a web based image editor using CamanJS plugin, and it's proving to be a blast but i need to create a flip horizontal function and it turns out CamanJS doesn't have a method for that, i'm thinking of flipping the canvas outside the Caman and reload it like this

```
context.translate(imageWidth / 2, imageHeight / 2);
context.scale(-1, 1);
context.drawImage(imageObj, - imageWidth / 2, - imageHeight / 2, imageWidth, imageHeight);
caman.reloadCanvasData();
```

But nothing happened, anyone can help?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what flip plugin might look like:

```
Caman.Plugin.register("flip", function () {
    var canvas, ctx;
    var width = this.canvas.width;
    var height = this.canvas.height;

    // Support NodeJS by checking for exports object
    if (typeof exports !== "undefined" && exports !== null) {
        canvas = new Canvas(width, height);
    } else {
        canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
    }

    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.translate(width, 0);
    ctx.scale(-1, 1);
    ctx.drawImage(this.canvas, 0, 0);

    this.replaceCanvas(canvas);
    return this;
});

Caman.Filter.register("flip", function () {
    return this.processPlugin("flip");
});
```

Comment: Looks like you copy/pasted code from https://github.com/prtksxna/ImageEditor/blob/master/resources/caman.flip.js

Answer (score 0):

If you're flipping an image that fills the canvas, translate to the right of the canvas.

```
context.translate( canvas.width,0  );
context.scale( -1,1 );
context.drawImage( imageObject,0,0 );
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, the problem is CamanJS use it's own context  while i try to flip it using the context outside caman, if i remove the caman the image flips just fine but if i do that i won't be able to use Caman filters

Comment: Couldn't you just flip the image in html canvas as above. Then save to an image: newImage.src=theCanvas.toDataURL().  Then use that flipped image as the starting point to feed into Caman.